# How to effectively use f2py in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy, gfortran, f2py

I need to iterate a Fortran program (ftmodule) through thousands of files (indus001.txt, indus002.txt, indus003.txt, indusxxx.txt). The Fortran program requires two inputs:

1. "Ln," corresponding to the number of rows of each input file
2. Each input file (called temporaryfile.txt)

The output of the Fortran program is a file called 'outputfile.txt.'

To do so, I have wrapped the Fortran program by using f2py and built a loop in python, as follows:

1. I have used os.listdir to iterate throughout the files
2. used array.shape to get the number of rows (ln) of each file
3. used np.savetxt to save the data of each 'indusxxx.txt' file into a 'temporaryfile.txt' that serves as input for the Fortran program
4. called the Fortran program
5. read the 'outputfile.txt' and save it as a new file that keeps the sequence

**The Fortran program works perfectly, but it only runs one case (probably the last one) when I use it in the loop. What problem could it be?**

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import os 
import pandas
import ftmodule # This is the f2py module

for i in os.listdir():
  if i.startswith('indus'):

    # Read Indus parameters from text file.

    values = pandas.read_fwf(i, index_col=False, header=None)
    wine = pandas.DataFrame(values)
    array = np.array(wine)
    rows, colums = array.shape
    lines = rows
    np.savetxt("temporaryfile.txt",array.to_numpy(),fmt=['%7.0f', '%7.0f', '%7.2f','%7.2f','%7.2f','%7.2f','%10.1f'])

    deform = ftmodule.ftmodule2(ln=lines) #calling the fortran program

    newoutput = pandas.read_fwf('outputfile.txt', index_col=False, header=None)
    nw = pandas.DataFrame(newoutput)
    np.savetxt("Nw_{}".format(i),nw.to_numpy(),delimiter=' ', fmt='%6.2f')
```

Note1: I want to avoid modifying the fortran program as much as possible. This is why I want to use python for running the loop.

Note2: I am sorry I am not allowed to share the fortran code.

Comment: You never use the `deform` variable. Why not?

Comment: @Olsgaard because I only used it to execute the program

Comment: Why do you load the file into pandas dataframe, then convert the dataframe to a dataframe, only to convert that dataframe to an array, and finally saving the exact same data back into a file? There is a lot of unnecessary code and I am sure it is causing trouble somewhere. My approach would be to read the number of lines, make a copy of the file, run the program, rename output and repeat. Consider solving this in bash: Something along the lines of `for f in indus*.txt; do ln=$(wc -l "$f"); cp "$f" 'temporaryfile.txt'; fortran myfortranprogram --ln "$ln"; cp 'outputfile.txt' "out_${f}"; done;`

Comment: @Olsgaard thank you. I do not have so much experience with bash. However, I have tried to run the bash script but it is only writing the same output from indus0001.txt several times. Like running the loop but only working with the first input file. I am using gfortran.

Comment: This has moved beyond a programming question and into a debugging. You need to look into if your fortran program is reading the file you expect it to, if your files actually have different content. Check each part of the loop individually (e.g., does the file you expect to be copied into the temp file actually get copied, does the fortran program read the file you expect it to read etc., etc.) If bash is too much for you, you can implement the same loop in any language you are comfortable with.

Comment: @Olsgaard Thanks a lot! I could figure it out. It was a a problem with the fortran code. And, finally, I reduced the unnecessary code and made it work in Python.